# Avoid overwritte files when .git push with .gitignore

Tags: javascript, git, gitlab

I have a project that is worked in local and then in cloud.
When we are in local we need to do some changes in some file to work well, and then rewrite this files to upload again when make the git push.

For example a file:

```
'use strict';
const mysql = require('mysql');

/* const dbConn = mysql.createPool({
  connectionLimit: 5,
  host: process.env.MYSQL_CONNECTION_STRING.split(':')[0],
  user: process.env.MYSQL_USER,
  password: process.env.MYSQL_PASSWORD,
  database: process.env.MYSQL_CONNECTION_STRING.split('/')[1],
  charset: 'utf8mb4'
});
module.exports = dbConn; */

const dbConn = mysql.createPool({
  connectionLimit: 5,
  host: 'localhost',
  user: 'root',
  password: 'Mraixa2015L',
  database: 'tool_bbdd',
  charset: 'utf8mb4'
});
module.exports = dbConn;
```

in local use mysql local with my credentials in cloud the others, and everytime i have to comment and uncomment to work.

this is one example, but i need to do things like this in other files.

I think if is possible to include in .gitignore file this files.
Inside my .gitignore

```
config/db.config.js
```

And when i make the git push, not upload this changes and not overwritte the data to use then in the cloud.

is it possible?
Thanks

Comment: Yes, you can add such config files to `.gitignore`, and that will solve it. Remember that you need to remove them (`git rm --cached config/db.config.js`) if already committed. What's the problem you are facing?

Comment: Typical approach would be to use environment variable, which, if set, points to your custom configuration file.

Answer (score 1):

The point is not about pushing. What will be pushed is what is the the commits.... whatever it is. Git can't just remove a file from a commit to push. What you should care about is about *committing* it in the first place.

If the file is already tracked, `.gitignore` makes no difference. You can ask git to ignore it if it is already tracked with `git update-index --assume-unchanged`.... or, what I do sometimes, is keep those changes in a private branch.... so you can *"easily"* apply them / unapply them

```
git show X/some-private-branch | git apply # boom! I have my changes there
# when I want to remove them
git show X/some-private-branch | git apply -r # The change is gone
```

Comment: ok so, if i not stage the changes before commit, this not overwritte the files in gitlab, when i make the push. 
And if maybe i have a stash with my local changes, i can apply everytime, after i make the git pull with new changes merged in my master, after create the new branch to continue work. ???

Comment: Keeping them in the stash is also a possibility.... but then you have to be _aware_ of where they are in order for you to apply them (considering that you will be adding/removing stuff from the stash)... and _sure_, you can keep the changes laying around and make sure not to _add_ them before you commit. You can even add _other_ changes from a file using _patch_ mode when adding... but it can become a nag. It's easier to just apply/unapplly them.

Comment: yes, i am looking for information for apply unapplly, because i never used it, and i don't understand all in the https://stackoverflow.com/users/2437508/eftshift0 response

Comment: what happens if in a file that is in your patch to apply yo have a change that you want to push, can you unapply the patch file, but stay this change??

Comment: Hmm..... it _should_ but you are going into corner cases.... you need to test... and that is for _unapplying_ and also for adding into index (so you can commit/push). You can add some changes of a file into index by using -i (`git add -i some-file`), that way you can _skip_ the sections that you do not want to add.

Answer (score 0):

The situation here is that you want to ignore some changes to tracked files with Git.  Unfortunately, as the [Git FAQ mentions](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitfaq#ignore-tracked-files), there's no way to do that with Git.  Specifically, using `git update-index` for this purposes doesn't work properly:

> It’s tempting to try to use certain features of `git update-index`, namely the assume-unchanged and skip-worktree bits, but these don’t work properly for this purpose and shouldn’t be used this way.

The easiest way to solve this problem is to include two separate files, one which has the production values and one which has the development values, both with names independent of the actual desired location, and then use a script to copy the correct file into the desired location, which *is* ignored (and not tracked).  You can even have that script adjust the development or production values to include additional data that's appropriate based on things like environment variables.